# How to avoid repeated while loops with C# event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms, while-loop, event-handling, async-await

In a **Windows Forms** application, i have a ComboBox element and need to run some code pieces periodically when ComboBox element changes.

The problem with code is, when ComboBox Text changes A to B or vice versa ,event handler triggers and previous **while(true) loops** are still running.

When event  handler is triggered, needs to run one infinite loop.

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string status = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Running on ui thread
            datagrid.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                status = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            });

            if (status == "A")
            {
                Work();
            }

            else if (status == "B")
            {
                anotherWork();
            }
            else if (status == "C")
            {
                someWork();
                break;
            }

            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
    });
}
```

Tried with ManualResetEvent, CancellationTokenSource, and bool check but none of them solved the problem.

What is the best practice to prevent repeated while loops?

Edit: Implemented timer already but wanted to while loop trick. I was doing bool check in a wrong way, Owen s answer is accepted.

Comment: why are you in a loop? have you considered using a `Timer`?

Comment: Daniel is correct that you should be using a timer. That said, the way to fix what you've got would be to have a private flag `bool _isInfiniteLoopRunning = false;` and set it to true when you start the infinite loop. In the event handler, check that flag before starting the loop. If it's true, exit the handler without starting the loop. What is "bool control"? What does that mean? Not that it matters -- just use a timer.

Comment: `but none of them solved the problem.` What did you actually do, for each of those attempts, and in what way did they fail to solve the problem?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I mean boolean check,  like Owen Pauling answer below.

Comment: I do not get it why people downvote anyway.. It is clear and sensible question.  I thought the timer already but just want to learn trick with while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a bool to check whether or not the loop is running:

```
private bool _loopRunning;

private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_loopRunning)
    {
        return;
    }

    _loopRunning = true;

    string status = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // stuff

        _loopRunning = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear the flag AFTER the task is complete :)

Comment: i have done this appraoach but when event handler trigger twice (A -> B). Previous loop is still running

Comment: @SerhatAtes Are you saying that now you want the loop to stop executing?

Comment: The event handler does indeed *trigger* but it returns right away. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: it is conceivable, that because there are multiple threads involved, that two separate calls to this handler could occur at the same time and that the second call could get past the boolean check before the variable is set.  It would probably be a good idea to use the `lock` statement to control access to the bool variable.  I'm not sure what consequences this would have in a UI context, however.

Comment: @mm8 Ed , I want that when event handler is triggered second time, previous ones while loop must be exited its execution otherwise multiple infinite loop executes at the same time.

Comment: I implemented in a wrong way last week, checked again now and  works properly, accepted Owen s answer.